# Updating the value inside session cart

Tags: php, session, foreach

```
$session_cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

foreach($session_cart as $item){
    foreach($item as $item2){
        if($item2['subject'] == "2014 ICAS - Computer Skills"){
            $item2['quantity'] == $sum;
            $item2['total'] == $total;
            $item2['level'] == $newlevelarray;
        }
    }
}
```

Guys I have the foreach loop above to update the session cart array if user click edit cart, but the foreach loop only updates the $session_cart variable array, it doesn't update to $_SESSION['cart']. How to update item inside the session cart without wiping the rest of the item inside the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use foreach loop that is why to modify elements you need to create reference via &

```
$session_cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

foreach($session_cart as &$item){
 foreach($item as &$item2){
    if($item2['subject'] == "2014 ICAS - Computer Skills"){
        $item2['quantity'] = $sum;
        $item2['total'] = $total;
        $item2['level'] = $newlevelarray;
    }
 }
}
```

When you do as &item then it's referenced not copied and the reference is modified not the copy. Also check your assigment operator which is "=" not "=="

From [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Comment: You're welcome :) PHP sometimes has some weird things and you should always check manual it's great source of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$session_cart` isn't modified, you have to [pass it by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) in your `foreach` loop, and the same goes for `$item`.

Also, it's `=` to assign values, not `==`

```
$session_cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

foreach($session_cart as &$item){
    foreach($item as &$item2){
        if($item2['subject'] == "2014 ICAS - Computer Skills"){
            $item2['quantity'] = $sum;
            $item2['total'] = $total;
            $item2['level'] = $newlevelarray;
        }
    }
}

$_SESSION['cart'] = $session_cart;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are mistakenly using `==`

```
$session_cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

foreach($session_cart as $item){
    foreach($item as $item2){
        if($item2['subject'] == "2014 ICAS - Computer Skills"){
            $item2['quantity'] = $sum;
            $item2['total'] = $total;
            $item2['level'] = $newlevelarray;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$session_cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

foreach($session_cart as &$item){
    foreach($item as &$item2){
        if($item2['subject'] == "2014 ICAS - Computer Skills"){
            $item2['quantity'] = $sum;
            $item2['total'] = $total;
            $item2['level'] = $newlevelarray;
        }
    }
}

$_SESSION['cart'] = $session_cart;
```

replaced `$item` with `&$item` [references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

updated `$_SESSION['cart']` at the end

Answer (score 0):

finish your code with this line:

```
$session_cart = unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
//do smth
$_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($session_cart);
```

Comment: Not enough, `$session_cart` isn't modified.

Comment: oh i see, sorry, you should serialize your object before store it to the session.